# how to get ForEach Loop and SetTimeout working with Angular 6

Tags: angular

I knew this question may have been asked before but believe most thread I search here does not address my issue.

I have **angularjs** code that I want to move to **angular 6**. All I want is to implement the Foreach loop in **angular6** judging from **angularjs** code below

**Angularjs code**

```
                 setTimeout(function() {
                        $scope.$apply(function(){


                        angular.forEach(res.data,function(item) {
                            $scope.crud_s.push(item);
                        });  

                        });
                    },500);
```

**This is what I have tried in angular6**

```
      getRecord(): void {
    this.crudService.getAll().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.crud_s = res;

// starting code issue


                                 setTimeout(function()=>{ 
                                    this.$apply(function(){ 

                                    angular.forEach(this.crud_s,function(item) {
                                       this.crud_s.push(item);
                                    }); 

                                    });
                                },500); 

    //end code issue

    //more codes will continues
     }
```

Comment: If moving from angularJs to angular6, please read what will be the equivalents of `$scope/$apply`. There are `changeDetector` references. But do you really need that? If there's a `setTimeout()` there will an auto change detection by angular itself. Also you will loose `this` reference if you are using functions. Please see `arrow` functions of ES6.

Comment: And what is `res.data`? Response from an HTTP request? Plain Array?

Comment: yes. this is how the Angularjs code is  


  $scope.getPosts = function(){
                
                $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'getData.php',
                data: {info:$scope.info}
                }).then(function successCallback(res) {
               
                   
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $scope.$apply(function(){ 


                             angular.forEach(res.data,function(item) {

Comment: Okay, so after understanding the differences use something like: `for(let eachKey in res.data) {}` can use this for both arrays and objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no angular.forEach availabile with Angular6, you need to use for loop. Also you are trying to push to same item to the same array, make sure the variable is different.

```
for(let item of this.crud_s){
  this.crud_s.push(item);  //this.crud_s should be new array
}
```

Comment: Sir, its seems that angular6 is not recognizing the code below 
                                 setTimeout(function()=>{ 
                                    this.$apply(function(){   it says this.$apply  is not define. can you help me further with the timeout  and $scope.apply function equivalent in Angular6. between thanks. waiting for your response

Comment: you need    setInterval(()=>{
   
},10000)

Comment: did the answer helpe

Answer (score 1):

Angular 6 uses Typescript as base language, so you need to write your code in with ts syntex. For "forEach" look you can write

```
let myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
myArray.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item);
});
```

and setTimeOut will be like that:

```
setTimeout(() => { //enter your forEach loop here }, 1000);
```

Also you do not need $apply and $digest here. Angular provide diffrent life cycle hooks here. Hope this will help you.